# Why is BA+CA=A(B+C) true but BA+CA=(B+C)A false in matrices?

Tags: matrices

Shouldn't it keep the same multiplication order?

Comment: Actually, it's the other way around.

Comment: When multiplication commutes (which it does for real numbers but not for matrices), you only need one distributive law, but when you don't have commutativity you need a left distributive law and a right distributive law. You need to keep track of which side you are multiplying on.

Answer (score 2):

Acutually, $BA+CA=A(B+C)$ is false. It happens that $BA+CA=(B+C)A$ but since, in general, matrices don't commute, $(B+C)A\neq A(B+C)$ in general.

Comment: So for example then AB + 2B = (A + 2)B, right?

Comment: @Alex If by $2$ you mean $2\times\operatorname{Id}$, then yes.